# Create desktop icon with custom image in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut, desktop

I don't know how to create shortcut icon with image

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\Datastudio"; Filename: "{app}\url.bat"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a desktop icon with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262254/how-to-create-a-desktop-icon-with-inno-setup)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`IconFilename` parameter of your `[Icons]` section entry](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection&anchor=IconFilename) to point to an .ico file (which you need to install somewhere):

```
[File]
Source: C:\path\to\theicon.ico; DestDir: {app}

[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\Datastudio"; Filename: "{app}\url.bat"; \
    IconFilename: {app}\theicon.ico
```