# How can I get inno setup to create a custom desktop icon? What do I need to change?

Tags: inno-setup

I am not very familiar with inno setup and am still learning. What do I need to change in this code to use gia.ico as the desktop icon? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "ABC"
#define MyAppURL ""
#define MyAppExeName "run.bat"
#define MyAppIcoName "gia.ico"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId=745745
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={localappdata}\{#MyAppName}
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
AllowNoIcons=no
PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputBaseFilename=GIA
OutputDir=.
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Excludes: "shinysetup.exe, setup.iss, .git*"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: shellexec postinstall nowait skipifsilent```
````

Comment: You did notice the `[Icons]` section, right? And check the excellent help file that comes with InnoSetup about how to use that section? Those are basic things that you should look into and experiment with before asking here as part of your efforts to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/74548301/850848 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/32262254/850848

Comment: @KenWhite I spent a few hours trying various things to no avail. I think I'm just not understanding the documentation, I primarily use R for dataviz and stats, so this is quite new to me. Forgive my naivety.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - do I need to include a path to my icon specifically in the [file] section, even if I already point there (I assumed the * means all files in the directory)? I primarily code in R, and inherited this project from a colleague.

Comment: The icon file has no be included into the installer. It does not matter if you include it with dedicated entry, or via wildcard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to point to my icon file specifically to ensure it’s included. For some reason the wild card didn’t work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).